# How to get an Integer from a String (contains letters and number)?

Tags: java, string, integer, letters-and-numbers

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
String letternumber = "Example - 123";
```

I want to output `"123"` but I need to get it from the string, I can't just do:

```
String number = "123";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(number));
```

Or I will get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Pattern and Matcher Classes.

```
String s = "Example - 123";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
        int num = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
        System.out.println(num);
}
```

Output:

```
123
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, 

I tried using the Pattern and Matcher classes, but a problem I encountered was that since I am loading the names of non-player characters in my game, and some of them have one word names, some have up to 4 word names, that it wouldn't work because the group number would be different for each non-player character name I want to select. The number I am trying to get from the String is their ID.

Edit: I see you edited your response, maybe I was using it completely wrong. I will try this. Thanks, you helped me earlier too. :)

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: Providing incomplete information gets you an incomplete answer.

Comment: @Avinash Raj Thank you so much!! It worked. I think I will look further into these Classes. They are extremely useful.